# Insert / Edit Rows by Selecting FK row

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, foreign-key

When inserting or editing rows ("Edit Top 200 Rows") for a table with a FK constraint, can the editor be configured to select the foreign row, rather than me having to look up the FK?

Answer (score 1):

No. You're referring to SQL Server Management Studio, presumably, and that behaviour doesn't exist there. There are other applications you can use that will leverage FKs in that way though.